# how to Run Django and React server together?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

I wanna know is it possible Running two server Django and React.js together?
every time I should to run Backend with `python manage.py run server` and then I should go to Frontend and Run `npm Start`

actually I have One Fullstack project with Subfolders Backend And Frontend

my question is we have any code to rune both servers together or Not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bash script that goes to each of your folder and runs those commands for you.

Something along the lines of:

```sh
cd /backend
python -d manage.py runserver

cd ../frontend
npm run start
```

Assuming your project resides in `app/backend` and `app/frontend`. Put this script in `app` as `start_servers.sh` for example. And run this like `bash start_servers.sh`

**Note:** This script probably won't run, because the `-d` flag to run the server in detached mode probably won't work. And I have not tested it. It maybe something you don't want. This script only demonstrates that it is possible, but it will need some tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

As I know,unfortunately,there is no way to run them both with just a line of code.This can be wrong though.